# Javascript loop

Tags: javascript, loops, increment

I've got a javascript snippet that loops through all inputs (all rows in a table) and if one checkbox is checked in a single row, it checks all checkboxes in all rows.

I actually need it to check a 2nd checkbox in the same row not all rows so I need to edit the javascript snippet, where it increments

```
//loop through all inputs
            for(i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var mainchecked = false;  

    function checkAll() {

        //get all input elements
        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

        //if the box is being checked
        if(!mainchecked) {

            //loop through all inputs
            for(i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                //does it have autocheck?
                if(inputs[i].className == 'autocheck') {
                    //then check the box!
                    inputs[i].checked = "checked";  
                }
            }
            mainchecked = true;
        } else {
            //box is being unchecked, uncheck everything
            for(i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                inputs[i].checked = "";
            }
            mainchecked = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Comment: Can you provide a sample html page? jsFiddle is a good place to put it... I don't get why you are looping through all checkboxes at once when you apparently want to be looping through each checkbox IN A ROW, as per your question.

Comment: Would you consider using jQuery? It could accomplish this in a few lines.

Comment: I don't need to loop thru all, just each row.
<td colspan="1" style="text-align:center">
<?PHP echo "<input type='checkbox' id='read' name='read'  class='autocheck'/>" ?> 
     </td>
                    
<td colspan="1"><!-- enter Favorite Check Box -->
<?php
echo "<input type='checkbox' id='favorite' name='favorite' 'onclick'=>'javascript:checkAll()' />";?>&nbsp;
</td>

Comment: When checking the favorite checkbox it means that you have read the row so I want it to check the read checkbox as well but only in the same row.

I am open to jQuery but thought this would be a minor edit in javascript.

Comment: link to screen shot of none checked
http://slographicarts.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/Capture_unchecked.png

link to screen shot of what happens when one is checked. I only need the same row in read column checked not all rows!
http://slographicarts.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/Capture_checked.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't loop through all inputs, loop through the table rows and process the inputs within each row. The following code assumes the controlling checkbox for the row is in the first input found within the row and that all other checkboxes in the row that this functionality applies to will have the class set to "autocheck"; I'll leave it to you to modify this as needed for your specific case (e.g., you might need to check whether `type=="checkbox"`).

I haven't tested this, but it should give you enough to go on.

```
function checkAll(){
   var _rows = document.getElementById("yourTableID").rows;
   var i,
       j,
       isChecked,
       inputs;

   for (i=0; i < _rows.length; i++) {
      inputs = _rows[i].getElementsByTagName("input");
      isChecked = inputs[0].checked;
      for (j=1; j < inputs.length; j++) {
         if (inputs[j].className == "autocheck") {
            inputs[j].checked = isChecked;
         }
      }
   }

}
```

UPDATE: just saw in your comments that you seem to be triggering this functionality from the `onclick` of the controlling checkboxes. If that is so then you can pass a reference to that checkbox to your function and then process only the row it is in, as follows:

```
<input ... onclick="checkAll(this);" ...>

function checkAll(cb){
       var _row = cb.parentNode.parentNode,
           j,
           isChecked = cb.checked,
           inputs;

          inputs = _row.getElementsByTagName("input");
          for (j=0; j < inputs.length; j++) {
             if (inputs[j].className == "autocheck") {
                inputs[j].checked = isChecked;
             }
          }
    }
```

Google "mdc parentnode" for more info.

Comment: the UPDATE, function checkAll(cb) was exactly what I needed. Thanks!